# why the full stop in my html code is printing in the next line?

Tags: html

```html
  <body>
    <h1>VARUN TEJA KOMIRISHETTI</h1>
    <p><em><strong><h2>student</h2></strong></em>.</p>

  </body>
```

why the full stop is printing in the next line?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: `h2` is a block element, it will always be on it's own line

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: h2 is a block element

Answer (score 1):

Because **h2** and every heading elements are block elements. All of block elements has 100% width, so there is no space for this dot in one line. If you change **h2** to **display: inline;** or **display: inline-block;**, then the dot will be in one line with student.

Answer (score 1):

Its because, all headings incliding `h2`is a block element, you can make it appear in same line by adding a class and, adding property `display: inline-block`

```css
.header-title{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>VARUN TEJA KOMIRISHETTI</h1>
    <p><em><strong><h2 class="header-title">student</h2></strong></em>.</p>
</body>
```